# MATLAB volume plots via transparent isosurfaces, like in Plotly

Tags: matlab, visualization

I'm looking for a volume visualization like [Plotly's `Volume`](https://plotly.com/python/3d-volume-plots/). I've tried most methods [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/volume-visualization.html), also tried [vol3d](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22940-vol3d-v2).

How can I get closer to Plotly's visual? I'm simply looking to have a mostly fully transparent 3D plot, where (as I understand) values are locally grouped and represented as a colored "cloud" - and be able to use 2D colormaps (e.g. turbo). It doesn't have to be strictly accurate (e.g. antialiased).

#### Plots

Closest results below - describing:

- `isosurface` & `isocaps`: colors are mapped incorrectly, max appears as min. The interior is also a bit too hollow (/ transparent).
- `slice`: for colors to make sense, `alpha` must be too low. Higher `alpha` clutters everything with low values. `alpha('color')` isn't transparent enough on inner values.
- `vol3d`: lack of transparency, and looks brickish.

Flipping sign and shifting input to `isosurface` / `isocaps` makes difference that I don't understand, and I can't make sense of docs' definition of the `isovalue` argument.

[image]

#### Code

```matlab
OPTS = {'iso', 'slice', 'vol3d', 'slice-color'};
OPT = OPTS{1};

[X, Y, Z] = ndgrid(linspace(-8,8,40), linspace(-8,8,40), linspace(-8,8,40));
D = sin(X.*Y.*Z) ./ (X.*Y.*Z) * 100;
D = max(min(D, 100), 20);  % clip to [20, 100]

figure
colormap('turbo')
% make cube
xdim = size(X, 1);
daspect([size(X,2)/xdim, 1, size(X,3)/xdim])

switch OPT
    case {'iso', 'vol3d'}
        view(3)
        axis tight
        
        camlight left
        camlight
        lighting gouraud

        if strcmp(OPT, 'iso')
            isosurface(D, 20)
            isocaps(D, 20)
            alpha(.5)
        else
            vol3d('CData', D);
        end
    case {'slice', 'slice-color'}
        g = linspace(-8,8,40);
        h = slice(g,g,g, D, g,g,g);
        set(h,'EdgeColor','none',...
            'FaceColor','interp',...
            'FaceAlpha','interp');
        if strcmp(OPT, 'slice')
            alpha(.01)
        else
            alpha('color')
        end
end
```

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'browser'

X, Y, Z = np.mgrid[-8:8:40j, -8:8:40j, -8:8:40j]
V = np.sin(X*Y*Z) / (X*Y*Z) * 100
V = np.clip(V, 20, 100)

vkw = dict(showscale=False, colorscale='turbo', surface_count=50, opacity=.2)
fig = go.Figure(go.Volume(x=X.flatten(), y=Y.flatten(), z=Z.flatten(),
                          value=V.flatten(), **vkw))
fig.show()
```

Comment: `isosurface` plots one surface. This surface is defined by where the volumetric data is equal to `isovalue`. I think this is the largest cause of the discrepancy between MATLAB and python. I suspect you would want to iterate over different values of `isovalue` in order to plot multiple surfaces. As a starting point - try replacing your current calls to `isosurface` with this: `for ii = 20:10:100; isosurface(D, ii, D); isocaps(D, ii); alpha(ii/1000); end`. `alpha` can also be a fixed value, but in this example the inner surfaces have higher alpha.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I need. Though, `alpha` sets it for the [_entire_ figure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77431216/10133797).

Comment: Feel free to submit as answer, with [corrected code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77431320/10133797). I ended up using nonlinear mappings (one piecewise-linear, another exponential).

Comment: You could also consider the [plotly package for MATLAB](https://plotly.com/matlab/3d-surface-plots/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isosurface` plots one surface. This surface is defined by where the volumetric data is equal to `isovalue`. I think this is the largest cause of the discrepancy between MATLAB and python.

I suspect you would want to iterate over different values of `isovalue` in order to plot multiple surfaces.

The closest I can get is this (thanks to Till's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77431216/set-alpha-of-individual-isosurfaces)):

```
if strcmp(OPT, 'iso')
    for ii = linspace(20, 100, 50)
        patch(isosurface(D, ii, D), 'FaceAlpha', (ii/400).^2, 'FaceColor', 'interp', 'LineStyle', 'none');
        patch(isocaps(D, ii), 'FaceAlpha', (ii/400).^2, 'FaceColor', 'interp', 'LineStyle', 'none');
    end
else ...
```

`alpha` can also be a fixed value, but in this example the inner surfaces have higher alpha - you can try tuning the values differently, but that was the closest I could get to plotly.

Comment: My exponential mapping up to `alpha=1`, for input values 0 to 100: `.0250739 * exp(.0368551*ii)`. Used [exponential interpolation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=exponential+interpolation&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22ExponentialFitCalculator%22%2C+%22data2%22%7D+-%3E%22%7B%7B0%2C+.01%7D%2C%7B50%2C+.2%7D%2C%7B100%2C+.9%7D%7D%22) (with different values).