# Set alpha of individual isosurfaces

Tags: matlab

I wish to achieve to the effect of

```matlab
for ii = 10:10:100
    isosurface(D, ii)
    isocaps(D, ii)
    alpha(ii/1000)
end
```

How can I do it?

---

It may involve `patch`, but I've not figured it out - using it turns everything black, and I need to assign coloring. I'd like to preserve everything as-is, and only change the alpha. Full example:

[image]

```matlab
[X, Y, Z] = ndgrid(linspace(-8,8,40), linspace(-8,8,40), linspace(-8,8,40));
D = sin(X.*Y.*Z) ./ (X.*Y.*Z) * 100;
D = max(min(D, 100), 20);  % clip to [20, 100]

figure
colormap('turbo')
view(3)
axis tight
camlight left
camlight
lighting gouraud

for ii = 10:10:100
    isosurface(D, ii, D)
    isocaps(D, ii)
    alpha(ii/1000)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's what you want, but inside the loop you can do this:

```
for ii = 10:10:100
    patch(isosurface(D, ii, D),'FaceAlpha',ii/1000,'FaceColor','interp','LineStyle','none')
end
```

Then your figure will look like this:
[image: Path with Isosurfaces]

Comment: Excellent! Though, fixing `'FaceAlpha', 0.1` plots slightly differently from my for-loop - not a dealbreaker, but would you know how to match them? (I've also tried with `patch(isocaps(` with same args)

Comment: Ah, I thought, you wanted that alpha depends on ```ii```. I don't know if you get totall equality between patch and isosurface here. If you remove the ```camlight``` for patch then it looks a bit closer but still not the same. What is your goal eventually?

Comment: Yes, I seek `ii`-dependence, but the point is to "keep _everything else_ same as in original code". Though, I've played around and don't mind it any more.

Comment: Okay got it. Glad, I could help a bit :)